# GCP Datalab - Increasing CPU utilization to ~100%

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I'm using `n1-highcpu-8` machine and running single notebook.
the CPU utilization is always below ~20%.
is it possible to use multi CPUs for utilization increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that automatically makes your notebook use multiple CPU cores; The notebook kernel will only ever use a [single CPU core](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/machine-type#considerations_when_choosing_a_vm_machine_type).

If you want to use multiple cores, then you have to either make your code explicitly run in parallel (e.g. take a look at the [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) ), or use a framework which does that for you.